# How to update two tables at the same time in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables, `SERVIS_GON_TABLO` and `STOK_TABLO`.

After I updated `SERVIS_GON_TABLO` a product, at the same time I want to update in stock table (`STOK_TABLO`) two different products.

I mean, I sent a product (from a barcode reader) to repair (`SERVIS_GON_TABLO`), and service location qty+1 and storage qty-1 .

But we sent a product wrongly and I changed to product to COMPUTER. In `STOK_TABLO` (stock table) barcode reader will be qty+1 to storage and service location qty will be qty-1. And COMPUTER will be qty-1 to storage and service location qty will be qty+1.

I use a gridview and with select command I sent them to the textboxes. Then with a stored procedure, I try to UPDATE tables. Could you help me with that stored procedure?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UPDATE_TABLE
    (@STOCKID NVARCHAR(100),
     @MODELID NVARCHAR(100),
     @QTY INT,
     @FROM NVARCHAR(60),
     @TO NVARCHAR(60),
     @TEDARIKID NVARCHAR(150),
     @TED_TEL NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
         @StockQTY INT,
         @YeniUrunID NVARCHAR(100),
         @Location NVARCHAR(100)

    --This part which I sent to service and update a table(SERVIS_GON_TABLO) 
    UPDATE SERVIS_GON_TABLO 
    SET URUNID = @URUNID,
        MODELID = @MODELID,
        TEDARIKID = @TEDARIKID,
        TEDARIK_TELEFON = @TED_TEL 
    WHERE SERVISID = @ID

    -- Below in other table I try to UPDATE at STOCK_TABLE which I sent to service new STOCK 
    UPDATE STOK_TABLO 
    SET ADET -= @ADET 
    WHERE URUNID = @URUNID AND LOKASYONID = @NEREDEN 

    UPDATE STOK_TABLO 
    SET ADET += @ADET 
    WHERE URUNID = @URUNID AND LOKASYONID = @NEREYE

    --LAST part which I pull back from the service
    UPDATE STOK_TABLO 
    SET ADET -= @ADET 
    WHERE URUNID = @YeniUrunID AND LOKASYONID = @NEREDEN

    UPDATE STOK_TABLO 
    SET ADET += @ADET 
    WHERE URUNID = @YeniUrunID AND LOKASYONID = @NEREYE

    SELECT * FROM SERVIS_GON_TABLO
END
```

Comment: What is it, specifically, you need help with? What about your procedure isn't working?

Comment: Can you run the procedure from inside SQL Server Management Studio?  SSMS has much better error message and should help you test code.  Create a Test procedure in SSMS and just pass the variables values to your procedure.  Once you get working in SSMS it should work in c#